# php artisan make:controller error class Rout not found

Tags: php, laravel

php artisan make:controller was working but now produces this error?

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Rout' not found

Comment: Sometimes when you have an error in your code artisan won't work. Do you have a class **Rout** somewhere in your application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you have a typo in your routes file, located at `app/Http/routes.php`.

You have `Rout` there instead of `Route`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **Rout** instead of **Route**

It must be a spelling mistake please check